# Shir Urinanim- Whats the diffrence?

Tags: words, hebrew, chanuka, song-poetry

In [Ma'oz Tzur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ma%27oz_Tzur#Text), it says:

> וּמִנּוֹתַר קַנְקַנִּים נַעֲשָׂה נֵס לַשּׁוֹשַׁנִּים
>   בְּנֵי בִינָה יְמֵי שְׁמוֹנָה קָבְעוּ שִׁיר וּרְנָנִים

What is the Difference between Shirim and Rinanim?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, there is the fact that רננים was needed to make the line rhyme. :)

R' Shlomo Aharon Wertheimer, in his ביאור שמות הנרדפים שבתנ"ך, [says](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=31481&pgnum=157) that רננה means the sound of a crowd of people (this from [Ramban to Job 3:7](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39727&pgnum=23)), while שיר means vocal singing (as in Zeph. 2:14).

So in Maoz Tzur, the meaning may be something similar: the Sages established Chanukah as a time for singing (שיר) Hashem's praises, and also for getting together in large crowds and talking (רננה) about the miracle.